# Sockets BeginReceive AsyncCallback issue

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am just trying to do a proof of concept with a little internal socket client/server.  I am just passing a string and will receive a specific string back.  e.g. Send--> "UCME" Receive-->"ICU"

I have been following MSDN examples on this,[Async Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and the Synchronous Client works as expected.  However I actually want the Asynchronous Client which does not.  It finishes the current `ReceiveCallback` and then hangs indefinitely.  I don't get an error, nothing.  Only clue is I see the following messages while F10(ing) right after it exits the

```
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback'
```

Any ideas?

```
private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public class StateObject

{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Comment: Pretty standard mistake, TCP is a *stream*.  You'll receive 4 bytes for "UCME", call BeginRead() again and that's where it ends because the client won't send anymore.  You have to know when you've received the entire message.  Standard way to do that is to encode the string length first so you know exactly how many bytes you are supposed to receive.

Comment: Pretty standard mistake is definetly believable.  Totally new to Sockets.  So, with that in mind, I thought an alterante way to accomplish this was to have an agreed(client/server) EOT?  You can't see it in the code above but I am doing that.  It's `private static string EOF = string.Format("<{0}>", (char)4);` and I use it like this-->`Send(client, "UCME" + EOF);`

Comment: The code above never checks for your EOT, so it would appear that Hans' comment still stands, right?  As an aside, an agreed EOT can work for small projects, but what if the EOT is actually part of the data at some point?  The better approach, if you're planning to expand this, is to encode the length of the message as part of a standardized header.  The header in my project includes 2 shorts (a sync word (e.g., 0xABCD) and a message type) and 1 int (the length) for a header of 8 bytes total.

Comment: @MattDavis: I understand that, I didn't want to bog it down with too much code, especially since I took the vast majority of it from the MSDN Async Socket Example.  So, in general, what would my `ReceiveCallback()` look like if I implemented length like you, and Hans Passant, suggest?

Comment: @HansPassant Did not intend to imply that you comment wasn't valid.  Sorry if it came across that way.

Comment: Typically, I read from the socket directly into a temporary buffer (~1KB) that is later copied into a master buffer (1MB) on another thread.  I then process my messages out of the master buffer.  For example, say the header has a 4-byte length field.  Read 4 bytes from the master buffer and determine if there's enough remaining data for a full message.  If so, extract it into a message object.  If not, wait for the next temporary buffer from the socket to be added to the master buffer.  Once a message is processed, the remaining data can be moved to the front of the buffer to reuse space.